# What programming languages does the Raspberry Pi support?

Tags: linux

As of now, I do not own a Raspberry Pi, but I really want to buy one. I really want to know what programming languages it supports. What programming lanaguages does it support, and does it support HTML 5 in its browser? I only know that it can run Python scripts and that there's a Minecraft Pi, so it must also support Java - but does it support anything else like C/C++ or C#?

Comment: This question shows no evidence of any research

Comment: The Pi supports almost anything that a regular Linux PC does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a linux computer, it supports basically tens if not hundreds of programming languages, you just have to install the support you need if it's not installed.

Besides Python, Java, C/C++ you may use PHP, bash scripting, AWK, assembly language, LUA, JS scripting, HTML/CSS (is it a programming language?), Clojure, Haskell, Erlang, Forth, Pascal, TeX, SQL, Ruby, Smalltalk and so on... it's by no means a complete list.

Comment: The question also specifically asks about C# - I believe this is possible using `mono` but it may not support the latest version of the specs. I've never tried this.

Comment: Haskell is pretty useless on RPi. Very hard to setup (manual fiddling with flags is required), takes hours to compile libraries and no crosscompilation means it is rather impractical.

Answer (score 2):

And importantly, [Mathematica (Wolfram Language)](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/).  Already installed and free.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that was a langauge, time for me to start learning it!

Comment: It will change your life forever.

Comment: Not as much as Java ;)

Comment: Ah, yes.  Java in a bad way.  :-)

Comment: :O no please don't say that, Java cover your ears while I cry

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi has a large suite of programming languages at your disposal. Pre-installed is the GCC compilation software. This allows you to program in languages such as C, C++, C# and (possibly) FORTRAN.

Also installed is the Java Development Kit. This allows you to compile and run Java programs.

The main programming language is Python with both version 2.7 and 3.2 installed already.

For shell scripting, Bash is available.

The Pi also allows for Ruby, Perl and Lisp.

If that isn't enough, you can always download other compilers and interpreters using apt-get or binaries off the web.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, it has the compiler included as well! Cant wait to buy my, to start coding. Not like windows and you have to install all of the compilers, SDK, and interpreters