# Porting Python code to RPi

Tags: python

I would like to port my script, that is great on desktop, to RPi. It is a general question, but just for an example I show my first lines:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
import cgi
```

I can put `pip list` and I dont see my modules, neither many modules seen on desktop **(this is the reason for this Question)**, however many are written in plain python, no compilation needed (IMHO).

- Is somebody working on it? 
  Or no progress expected? Can one manage by himself?

I searched a bit [Can I run Python 3.3+ on Raspbian Jessie?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37244/can-i-run-python-3-3-on-raspbian-jessie) and [What programming languages does the Raspberry Pi support?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15480/what-programming-languages-does-the-raspberry-pi-support), but I have not a clear mind about the depths of support of Python.

In [Build something that requires dh-python](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19899/build-something-that-requires-dh-python) I see somebody tackled the problem, but the idea is not very clear to me.

**Edit:** if the question is downvoted, would be very nice to give a hint where is a problem. Thank you
**Edit2:** http.server cannot by found

**Edit3:** The question deserved -1. Details in my answer bellow

Comment: I actually used a short webserver code, that is proxy the open-street-maps servers. This way it is possible easily to make an offline gps map system for RPi. Pitty I cannot get through

Comment: You can use `pip` to install Python packages on the Pi - which in this case is more or less a general purpose computer. Some packages require compiling which could take some time on the Pi (e.g. `numpy` - it's quite heavy, takes hours). But most other packages should work fine. Just give it a try.

Comment: I wrote in text, that I tried ```pip list``` - I will edit with explicite - the modules dont exist. So I gave a try, now I need some hint

Comment: `pip list` shows the packages installed not the packages on the repo. Did you try to install them `pip install <name>`? Or `pip3` for that matter.

Comment: The http and cgi modules are built in - you dont need pip to use them. Have you tried to run your code?

Comment: ``` File "./webmap.py", line 3, in <module>
    from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
ImportError: No module named http.server```. Maybe I should install something? Thaaaat would be.....

Comment: @Ghanima - oh, I see, yes, I tried ```sudo pip install http```, no help, ```sudo pip install http.server``` - i get no response - do you mean that this is that compilation that takes hours? ok... this would by my answer

Comment: Sorry -
```  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement http.server
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for http.server```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help. I should have put the question accurately - but I did not know how. Now I would like to share my finding.

1/ **Old RPi** - it is important the RPi version - my code did not work, partially because I tried it on old RPi with debian wheezy. From now on I stick to RPi3, one can save lot of pain.

2/ **Different Pythons** - I have miniconda3 installed...now I see there are

1. python 2.x. in /usr/bin/
2. python 3.x  in /usr/bin
3. miniconda local install (that was my case and my problems, dont ask me why)

   I finally got successful with orignal python3 i.e. `#!/usr/bin/python3` in the script.

3/ **apt installs** - many problems were solved by `sudo pip3 install something-missing`. But sometimes, I had to use repositories like `apt-get install python3-tk`.

I have not yet all working, but numpy, http, staticmaps, tkinter are installed and I can continue. Thank you guys, discussions helped me, at least I knew it was my problem, not RPi.